# How to get address from img tag without regular expressions in tinymce

Tags: javascript

I need to wrap the  < img > tag in  < a >  tag, for this it needes to get the address of the picture. 
How to do this without using regexp?

And also i need to know width of the picture,
'onload' function breaks the event 'BeforeSetContent'

```js
        ed.on('BeforeSetContent', function (e) {
                if (e.content.startsWith("<img")) {
    var s = e.content.replace(/\<img src=\"(.+)\" alt.+\>/i,'$1');
 console.log('SRC: '+s);
                                          
//            var img = new Image();        
//            img.src = s;                  
//            img.onload = function() {     
// console.log('img-width: '+img.width);    
//            if (img.width > 450){         
    e.content = '<a class="ajax-modal modal_image hover_image"  href="' + s + '">' + e.content + '</a>';
//                }
//            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want open new window when clicking img, you can do this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName === 'IMG' && event.target.src && /^http/.test(event.target.src)) {
    event.preventDefault()
    window.open(event.target.src)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question, if your image has an id then:

```
var imgsrc = document.getElementById("yourImageId").src;
```

If it does not have an id then use the parent e.g.:

```
var imgsrc = document.querySelectorAll('#imgParentDiv img')[0].src
```

Answer (score 0):

i could get the address using  jQuery

```js
 ed.on('BeforeSetContent', function (e) {
    if (e.content.startsWith("<img ")) {
  var objC = $(e.content).filter(':first');
  var src = objC.attr('src');
    e.content = '<a class="ajax-modal modal_image hover_image"  href="' + src + '">' + e.content + '</a>';
    }
});
```

how can i get the width of the picture using jQuery and my created object 'objC' ?